# Interfaces in abstract and inherited classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, interface, abstract-class

For example I have an abstract class which has the `IEquatable` interface. Based on the properties of this class I want to implement the `Equals` method in itself (because inherited classes will check equality by these base properties):

```
abstract class Site : IEquatable<Site>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public Site() { }
        public Site(string name, string adress, int year)
        {
            Name = name;
            Adress = adress;
            Year = year;
        }

        public abstract bool CheckIfNew();

        public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            if(ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return GetType() == other.GetType() && Equals((Site)other);
        }

        public bool Equals(Site other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return other.Name == Name && other.Adress == Adress;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode() ^ Adress.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Suppose I have two inherited classes. They will both have `IComparable` interfaces for sorting them in a list. This is one of them:

```
class Museum : Site, IComparable<Museum>
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        private int[] WorkDays { get; set; }
        public bool HasGuide { get; set; }
        public decimal TicketPrice { get; set; }

        public Museum(string name, string adress, int year, string type, int[] workDays, bool hasGuide, decimal ticketPrice)
            : base(name, adress, year)
        {
            Type = type;
            WorkDays = workDays;
            HasGuide = hasGuide;
            TicketPrice = ticketPrice;
        }

        public bool CheckAvailability(int weekDay)
        {
            return WorkDays[weekDay - 1] == 1;
        }
        public override bool CheckIfNew()
        {
            DateTime curent = DateTime.Now;
            int difference = curent.Year * 12 + curent.Month - Year * 12;
            return difference < 24;
        }
        public bool Equals(Museum other)
        {
            return base.Equals(other);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + string.Format($" {Type, -20} | {(HasGuide ? "Taip" : "Ne"), -5} | {TicketPrice, 6}");
        }


        public int CompareTo(Museum other)
        {
            return TicketPrice > other.TicketPrice ? 1 : (TicketPrice < other.TicketPrice ? -1 : 0);
        }
    }
```

Does this inherited class now have both `IEquatable` and `IComparable` interfaces? Should I implement `Equals` method differently in inherited class if I'm checking for equality only by base class properties? Should I add `IComparable` interface to the base class and make the `CompareTo` method abstract? If, for example, I would like to store these inherited types in a custom list that only accepts types with these two interfaces, what would be the best way to implement these interfaces? I could go one way or another and it would still, in my opinion, work, but what would be the right and safe way to do this?

Comment: To be clear your inherited class has IEquatable<site> and IComparable<museum>  interfaces. To your museums when ordered can take in all the musuem properties. But when evaluated for eqaulity it can only compare data in the base class, this might mean if you have 2 museums with the same address, name year etc but a different ticket price for example, they would be consider equal by the IEquatable interface but not by the IComparable

Comment: you could override Equals(Site other) and do down casting in the sub class, but thats not recommended

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if `Site` implements `IEquatable` and `Museum` implements `IComparable` then one could say that `Museum` implements both of these interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of minor differences between Abstract Classes and Interfaces, but one big difference:

**Abstract classes** are in the inheritance chain. This makes it a primary, *exclusive* purpose. A Window or Form can not also be a DBConnection

**Interfaces** are not in the inheritance chain.

The limit about not beign able to declare fields, was invalidated with Properties. If it was no completely removed otherwise.

The limit of not providing Function Implementations, was [removed with C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)

A abstract class that "gathers" interfaces is a very common sight.

> Should I implement Equals method differently in inherited class if I'm checking for equality only by base class properties?

You should override it anyway. If it adds nothing to change equals, the implemenation is simple:

```
    public override bool Equals(Museum other)
    {
        return base.Equals(other);
    }
```

If it does, you you can add that implementaiton.

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods):

Comment: So what you're saying is that inherited class doesn't really have the base class interfaces?

Comment: @EIMA Quite the opposite. Interfaces that are "woven" into the Inheritance chain, stay with it. Look at DbConnection vs SqlConnection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection | Sql Takes all that Db is - interfaces included - adds the ICloneable interface and then changes some implementations (in particular stuff like Open(), wich is only abstract in Db.

Comment: @EIMA Note that one class can get the same interface from several angles. IDbConnection extents IDiposeable. Yet DbConnection stil adds IDisposeable to IDbConnection and others.